# Eclipse EGit changes folder names after Pulls

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm having trouble using EGit - specifically when pulling.

Basically, I cloned a Git repository in Eclipse using "Clone a git repository and add repository to this view" in Git Repositories view in Eclipse. 
After that, I imported the Git project and used the "import using existing Eclipse project tab".

However, this changes the names of the packages. Instead of having a src folder that contains all the packages ("Model", "Controller", "Player" etc), it changes all the names to the  packages to "src.Model", "src.Player" etc.

This is what the remote repository looks like

[image: This is what the remote repository looks like]

And this is what happens when I import the git project:

[image: And this is what happens when I import the git project]

Because the package names had changed, it would compile. So initially I changed the package names back to their original (src.Player -> Player). However, when I pull, it changes all the package names to start with src.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: If the package names in the repo are authoritative then maybe you should change your local build to match it.

Comment: Your project folder (instead of `src`) is configured by mistake as a source folder: in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Source_ remove the project folder and add the `src` folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your project folder instead of `src` is configured by mistake as a source folder:

1. In ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, in the tab ***Source* remove the project folder** and **add the `src`** folder instead.
2. **Commit and push the file `.classpath`** which stores this project-specific setting